# Military report

Tags: civilization-6

Is there a military report like in Civ5 where you could list all your units, see their health status and experience? A fast and convenient way to locate all units of a certain type would be very welcome, but I couldn't find anything like that. Did I miss it or has Civ6 no such report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 1.0.0.26 there is no way to see this information as you wanted.

There is a mod called "Unit Report Screen" and as of version 1.51 you can see a more detailed list of your units as well as active trade deals from the report screen.

Here is a link http://forums.civfanatics.com/resources/unit-report-screen.25396/

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing is the unit list that appears when you click a unit's name. It only displays the name of the unit and if it is or isn't asleep, fortified, or trading (quite why that AT team is trading is unclear).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the "Reports" button in the top bar of the game UI. Then, in the Reports window that will appear, click the "Collapse All" button.

Now, scroll down and you can see a lits of your units and their maintenance costs per turn in the "Unit Expenses" section.

Comment: Is this instructions on how to find the reports? You might want to give more details on where to find these things or where they can be accessed?